# Checking if the sums of the levels of a Binary Tree are equal

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm trying to figure out a function in c++ to calculate the sums of all the levels of a binary tree and then checking if those sums are all equal, and returning TRUE if they are.

So for example, if the first node is 10, the sum of its children has to be 10, and the sum of their children has to be 10, and so on...

I'm having truble comparing the sums without the recursions getting in the way. And the comparison has to be done in the function itself, not the main.

If you could figure it out it would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please show a [mre]

Comment: My idea was to record the value of the sums in an array which would be incremented in the recursive call and thus occupy a different position for every level.  The problem is that I can't figure out a way to compare the sums before the values of an entire level have been recorded in the array. I don't know if I'm explaining it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have defined the Node data as follows

```
struct TreeNode {
     int val;
     TreeNode *left;
     TreeNode *right;
     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
};
```

Then you can perform level order traversal without recursion as follows.

1. Initialize a queue
2. store the root node in the queue
3. now traverse childrens until the queue is emtpy
4. while traversing, if you find left or right childs you have to push them again into the queue

Here's the basic code that does what you wanted

```
bool equalSums(TreeNode* root) {
        if(root == nullptr){
            return true;
        }
        
        queue<TreeNode*> q;
        
        //push the root
        q.push(root);

        int sum = root->val; //save the current root value

        int len;
        TreeNode *temp;

        while(!q.empty()){
            int s = 0; //keep track of the next levels sum

            len = q.size(); //size of queue is number of elements at that level
            
            for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
                temp = q.front();
                q.pop();
                
                s = s+temp->val;
                
                if(temp->left)
                    q.push(temp->left);
                if(temp->right)
                    q.push(temp->right);
            }
            
            // break if sum is not equal to sum of node values in current level
            if(s != sum)
                return false;
        }
        
        // else return true
        return true;
    }
```

I hope this answered your question.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand most of it but since I'm not too familiar with using queues (I usually use recursion in these cases) could you please clarify a bit of what is going on in the for loop?

Comment: before the for loop, we are storing the size of the queue in the len variable. The size of the queue is always the number of nodes at that particular level. For the first level, the size will be 1, because queue contains only one node. We'll pop that and add it's left and right childs into the queue. In this way, you'll fill up the queue for a level. It's better to do on paper. Now, recursion does not work here, because, recursion uses call stack. It works as depth first search. So, you'll never add up nodes in a particular level, instead, you will end up adding nodes of different levels.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you again.